# Paros Proxy 3.2.13 & windows 7

Tags: windows-7, proxy

After installing Parosproxy-3.2.13.exe on Windows 7 64 bit, I am not able to run it. It is getting stuck on User license page. Can someone help/guide?

Answer (score 1):

You are using 64 bit JRE, but Paros is working with 32 bit only. You need to instal 32 bit JRE and set right path to java.exe in startserver.bat

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Java 64Bit (JRE)
2. Reboot
3. Install Java 32Bit https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp
4. Open "C:\Program Files (x86)\Paros"
5. Run startserver.bat